# CFileDialog as child of QWidget

Tags: qt, mfc, integration

Yes, I know, one should not mix different platforms, but I am working on a Qt application and now we have a new requirement: a standard Windows Open File Dialog should be used in place of a QFileDialog.

So I would like to create a CFileDialog that is a child of a QWidget. I have found a question related to the inverse problem: QWidget as a child of an existing MFC component but nothing about my specific issue.

My plan is to write a wrapper class

```
class FileStdWDialog : CFileDialog
```

with a constructor

```
FileDirStdWDialog(QWidget *parent, ...);
```

and map this to a call to the superclass constructor

```
CFileDialog(..., ..., ..., ..., ..., CWnd* pParentWnd, ...)
```

So, if I understand correctly, my problem boils down to mapping
a QWidget * to a CWnd *. Do you know if there is an easy way to do this?

**Update**

Thanks for the hints. Probably, getting the HWND for a QWidget and
converting this to CWnd * is the right solution. I will try this way.

Comment: This question isn't internally consistent -- if you want to open a standard Windowws Open File Dialog then just do so, in this scenarion a QWidget is neither the parent nor the child: dialogs are standalone.

Comment: I do not know much of MFC and since there is a parameter pParentWnd I thought I should provide a value for it. I will try with NULL, maybe it works.

Comment: Unless you need the some special functionalities of the windows file dialog that Qt doesn't expose, you can just use the static QFileDialog functions and they will use the platform-standard file dialog.. take a look at this : [http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfiledialog.html#details](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfiledialog.html#details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `::GetOpenFileName` and `::GetSaveFileName`. Those are the Win32 functions that `CFileDialog` wraps, I think. So you wouldn't need MFC.

By the way, starting with Windows Vista, it is recommended to use the [Common Item Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), rather than the standard Open and Save dialogs.

Comment: I looked into the documentation. As far as I understand GetOpenFileName() requires an OPENFILENAME struct. This struct has a field HWND hwndOwner; I guess I have the same problem here (?)

Comment: Try passing NULL, and see what happens. The doc's say you can do it.

Comment: @Giorgio I've never used Qt, but I suspected that if the widgets are "windows" running in a Windows environment, they must have an HWND. So I've googled and found [this](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-10/thread00800-0.html), which says, basically, "On Windows, WId is typedef HWND". So you do have an HWND if you really need it.

Comment: @Giorgio If an answer answered your question, you should "accept" it (click on the tick next to it). It's part of the etiquette of the site, plus it awards you some reputation.

Comment: I am still trying to apply the answers and encountered some problems. Using Qt static functions does not help since I need a dialog in which I can choose either a file or a folder. Qt static functions allow only one of the two. I also did not manage to apply the solution with WId because, as far as I understand, the conversion to CWnd * is not always possible (CWnd::FromHandlePermanent()) or safe (CWnd::FromHandle()). I am still googling for an answer on this. I will update the main question and accept an answer as soon as I am done.